# Error cs1061 Is Showing Up

Tags: unity

I've been looking into this online but can only find similar cases that don't really match mine and because of that I'm having a little trouble finding a clear answer to how to fix this code. Please help and thank you.[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your error message and code as text, never as images. Text is searchable, so users can find your question, accessible to screen-readers and translation tools to widen the pool of experts who can help you, and copy-and-pasteable to help folks reproduce your problem or author solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that Vector3 does not contain a member called c.

If you double-click your error, it will take you to this line:

```
if( transform.position.c < -10 )
```

It looks like you meant to type "x" there, not "c".

Please read your error messages carefully in future so you can solve typos like this more quickly.